# Bootstrap 2 column 3 square layout doesn't fill page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having some issues with making my bootstrap layout fill the whole page. This is the jsbin for what I currently have: http://jsbin.com/tibusakuci/edit?html,css,output

[image]

I'm having trouble making the grid fill the entire page. I want it to look like this (filling the entire screen):

[image]

With it looking like this on mobile screens:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas of why my code won't fill the whole screen when I take out the min-heights? Using bootstrap. Using height: 100% doesn't work either.

*Currently the boxes only fill half the screen

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove padding from the `container-fluid` and `col-*`. You can use `vh` for full hieght, and adjust this accordingly for 33% height on smaller screens.

```
.content {
  background: pink;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.sidebar-top{
  min-height: 50vh;
  background: yellow;
}
.sidebar-bottom{
  min-height: 50vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .content,
    .sidebar-top,
    .sidebar-bottom {
      min-height: 33vh;
    }
}

.row.no-gutter {
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0;
}
.row.no-gutter > [class*='col-'],
.container-fluid {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

**Working demo:** http://www.codeply.com/go/r3Rdffxi7A

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** The follow code will fix your gutter issues. But it looks like your main issue is with the fluid container not filling the entire page.

**CAUSE / SOLUTION:** According to this github issue - [Fluid Layout with 100% height #1671](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1671) - there is no "out of the box" solution. Try implementing one of the few solutions (with jsfiddle code) in that issue thread.

#### PREVIOUS ANSWER (partially obsolete)

#### Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/rilihit/1/edit?html,css,output

### STEPS

1. Remove the `margin-bottom` declaration from `.row > div` and from `.sidebar-bottom`.
2. Declare this css in your custom css file to remove the default bootstrap column gutter. This code is responsive and will work for all column sizes

`.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
        padding-right:0;
        padding-left:0;
    }`

3. Finally, in your HTML, add the `no-gutter` to the `row`s like so.

Here's the complete HTML and CSS code. I modified your jsbin code and tested it. (I made the `sidebar-bottom`'s `min-height = 160px;` so that the `min-height` values for the 2 add up to the `min-height` value for the `content` and nicely line up in desktop view. )

```css
.row > div {
  background-color: green;
}
.header,
.footer {
  background: blue;
}
.content {
  background: pink;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.sidebar-top {
  min-height: 140px;
  background: yellow;
}
.sidebar-bottom {
  min-height: 160px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


  <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="sidebar-top"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutter">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="sidebar-bottom"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Related Reference / Reading: [Bootstrap 3 Tips and Tricks You Still Might Not Know](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-still-might-not-know#optionally-remove-the-gutter-padding-from-columns)

Comment: Thank you for the help and detailed response! Maybe I should've been more clear (I edited the question), I am having trouble making the three squares fill the *entire* screen. Right now, they only go down to half the screen using the hard coded height values. I'm trying to make their height's 100% of the screen. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

remove padding and margin of surrounding, and remove the negative left and right shift.